connect() failed (111: Unknown error) while connecting to upstream. on odoo 16, nginx as reverse proxy and ubuntu 22
Here is the error i saw in nginx error log:
2024/11/08 02:58:29 [error] 299885#299885: *432 connect() failed (111: Unknown error) while connecting to upstream, client: X.X.X.X (my ip address), server: x.com (my domain name), request: "GET /websocket HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:42162/websocket", host: "x.com(my domain name)"
Steps to reproduce:

go to any product page
click smart button to view On Hand Quantity
odoo will try to get the data via api call /call_button
but its just stuck there, nothing happened.

Notes:
all exact same config works on my other server which is on ubuntu 20, but this one is error on ubuntu 22
Here is my nginx config:
upstream my-upstream {
    server 127.0.0.1:40162;
}
upstream my-upstream-im {
    server 127.0.0.1:42162;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name my-domain.com;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://my-upstream;
    }
}

server {
    server_name my-domain.com;
    # listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen 443 ssl;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/my-domain.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/my-domain.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

    proxy_buffers 16 64k;
    proxy_buffer_size 128k;

    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Host  $host;
    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For   $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP         $remote_addr;
    proxy_next_upstream error timeout invalid_header http_500 http_502 http_503 http_504;

    client_max_body_size 2000M;
    access_log /var/log/ptbi-trial-access.log;
    error_log /var/log/ptbi-trial-error.log;
    
    location /websocket {
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";        
        proxy_set_header REQUEST_URI $request_uri;  # Add this line
        proxy_connect_timeout   3600;
        proxy_read_timeout      3600;
        proxy_send_timeout      3600;
        send_timeout            3600;
        proxy_pass http://my-upstream-im;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_redirect off;   
        proxy_connect_timeout   360000;
        proxy_read_timeout      360000;
        proxy_send_timeout      360000;
        send_timeout            360000;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header REQUEST_URI $request_uri;  # Add this line
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
        proxy_pass http://my-upstream;
        if ($request_method = 'OPTIONS') {
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, PUT, OPTIONS';
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'Access-Token,DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,X-Openerp-Session-Id';
            add_header 'Access-Control-Max-Age' 1728000;
            add_header 'Content-Type' 'text/plain charset=UTF-8';
            add_header 'Content-Length' 0;
            return 204;
        }
        if ($request_method != 'OPTIONS') {
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, PUT, OPTIONS';
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range';
            add_header 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' 'Content-Length,Content-Range';
        }
    }

    gzip on;
    gzip_min_length 2000;
}

and here is my odoo conf, on ports section:
proxy_mode = True
xmlrpc_port=40162
xmlrpcs_port=41162
longpolling_port = False
gevent_port = 42162
workers = 2
xmlrpc_interface = 127.0.0.1

My python version is: 3.8.2
Is it really that odoo 16 doesn't support ubuntu 22?
Any idea please?
